# Android Studio: "attempting to assign weaker access privileges" error on Room Database implementation

Tags: java, android, android-room, access-modifiers

I am trying to implement room database, I have gone through steps on [Official Website](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room), and 'AppDatabase.java' file is like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static AppDatabase instance;
    public static synchronized AppDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        if (instance==null){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    AppDatabase.class, "app_database").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And dependencies I have used for room:

```
    // Room Database
    def room_version = "2.4.2"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version"

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0-alpha02"

    // Room Database
```

It returns 2 errors here:

```
onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in <anonymous com.example.testdb1.room.AppDatabase_Impl$1> cannot override onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in Delegate
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

```
onValidateSchema(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in <anonymous com.example.testdb1.room.AppDatabase_Impl$1> cannot override onValidateSchema(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in Delegate
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

It was working before the 'Chipmunk' version (was working in 'Bumblebee'), but it started throwing these errors.

What is going on here?

Comment: i'm currently starting out with android programming and got the same problem. after removing the unnecessary optional dependencies and only keeping the core (runtime & compiler), everything worked fine for me. might worth a try for you

Comment: They must have the same version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix this error for Jetpack Compose and Paging 3 you need to use only these libraries. The reason causing errors is that ktx and the runtime dependency clashes if their versions don't match. All the dependencies must have the same version

```
//ROOM
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1"
implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.6.1"

// Paging 3.0
implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha15'
```

Answer (score 14):

I got this error because I used

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.0-rc01'
```

with

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3'
```

and library

```
androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.0-rc01
```

is dependent on

```
androidx.room:room-common:2.5.0-rc01
```

so I finished with two same libraries but with different versions

```
androidx.room:room-common:2.5.0-rc01
androidx.room:room-common:2.4.3
```

after switching back to

```
androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1
```

error was gone.

Comment: Same for me. I use work-runtime and it works with androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.0-alpha04 but not with androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.0-beta01.

Comment: downgrading work manager dependency to: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1 , helped alot

Answer (score 7):

By [Никандрова Елизавета's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72518409), I have found that the source of the problem was one of the optional implementations that I have added from official website.

These dependencies was enough to run my code:

```
    def room_version = "2.4.2"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, I have just encountered this problem too, seems that you are copying the code from the official guidance.
It seems to be the problem of "androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0-alpha02" so the solution is to replace it with the latest stable version(2.4.2 currently) or just use the variable `room_version`
And you can check the latest version on: https://androidx.tech/artifacts/room/room-paging/
So you just need to replace it with the following code to solve this problem

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.4.2"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version"

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version"
}
```

Comment: if you are not using paging feature, you can comment  it out

Answer (score 5):

The problem occured after I changed the `androidx.work:work-runtime` implementation from version `2.7.1` to version `2.8.0` while having the following dependencies

`implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3"`

`annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3'`

I upgraded the room version to `2.5.0` and the problem is resolved

Answer (score 2):

I had same error after upgrading to `compileSdk 33` using

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3'
```

I found that after the upgrade there is an implicit dependency to `2.5.0-beta01`:

[image: Dependencies in IDEA]

so I just upgraded to `2.5.0-beta01`

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0-beta01'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-beta01'
```

and the error was gone

Answer (score 1):

I tried to comment every dependency one by one; changed version one by one at a time.

```
    def roomVersion = "2.4.1"
//    //def roomVersion = "2.4.3"
//    //noinspection GradleDependency
//    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
//    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
//    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
```

It occurred to me that:

```
//    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
```

above comment was responsible to generate the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation
> for com.safehaven.data.di.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist

Hence this library that is commented is responsible in the generation of this file `AppDatabase_Impl` where this error is coming.

So now this library is to be dealt with.

Secondly the `Delegate` class that is used in `RoomOpenHelper`

has these codes:

```
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        open fun onValidateSchema(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase): ValidationResult {
            validateMigration(db)
            return ValidationResult(true, null)
        }
```

and

```
override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    val isEmptyDatabase = hasEmptySchema(db)
    delegate.createAllTables(db)
    if (!isEmptyDatabase) {
        // A 0 version pre-populated database goes through the create path because the
        // framework's SQLiteOpenHelper thinks the database was just created from scratch. If we
        // find the database not to be empty, then it is a pre-populated, we must validate it to
        // see if its suitable for usage.
        val result = delegate.onValidateSchema(db)
        if (!result.isValid) {
            throw IllegalStateException(
                "Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: ${result.expectedFoundMsg}"
            )
        }
    }
    updateIdentity(db)
    delegate.onCreate(db)
}
```

clearly both are public, while in `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback _openCallback` class that instantiates with this abstract class in `AppDatabase_Impl` class, exposes these methods with protected access modifier which lowers the visibility of the overridden methods.

Hence causing error.

This should be fixed.
Surprisingly I got this error a week ago. It was resolved by using one of the answer (here, in the same question) as method (I am clueless, how it did), it has surfaced again and now not going away.

For this very reason I recommend at least myself, not to use Room Database. I will move to ORMLite or SQLite database as before.

Comment: Thanks `https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233251/e-net4-the-comment-flagger`, This edit worked and I started getting noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing room version fixed it for me

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0-rc01"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same errors and I could solve issues doing as below in build.gradle(app).

In 'plugins' block, below code was added;

```
id 'kotlin-kapt'
```

In 'dependencies' block, below codes were added;

```
def room_version = "2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the code -

```
 def room_version = "2.4.3"
        implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
        kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

and replace with this one -

```
 def room_version = "2.4.3"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
```

Comment: Sure, the build error is gone, but so is the Database_Impl: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for xxxxx.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist`