# Android: Room stopped working after upgrading to version 2.4.3

Tags: android, android-room

Android: The Room database stopped working after upgrading to version 2.4.3. The application complains about the AppDatabase_Impl generated file.

> AppDatabase_Impl.java:72: error: onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in
> <anonymous com.mobile_solutions.mycar.database.AppDatabase_Impl$1>
> cannot override onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in Delegate
> protected void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
> ^   attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public

AppDatabase:

```
@Database(
    entities = [
        Service::class,
        Profile::class,
        WorkItem::class,
        Auto::class,
        Recommendation::class,
        TechVisit::class,
        NotificationSimple::class,
        Expense::class
               ], version = 85, exportSchema = false
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun myCarDao(): MyCarDao?
}
```

I am getting such error:

```
AppDatabase_Impl.java:72: error: onCreate(Support SQLite Database) in <anonymous com.mobile_solutions.mycar.database.AppDatabase_Impl$1> cannot override onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in Delegate
      protected void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
                 ^
```

attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public

What to do about it?

Comment: Did you tried to do full clean (or wipe build folder at all)? maybe `AppDatabase_Impl.java` stays there from build with previous version

Comment: Yes. Several times. Build -> Clean Project and than Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: maybe you update runtime but not compiler (annotationProcessor )?

Comment: What do you mean? I updated my answer ^^

Comment: @Selvin I also deleted 'build' folder and than rebuild project. The same error.

Comment: @Selvin my room dependencies
// Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3"

Comment: so I'm out of concepts :/ maybe bug in library itself ...

Comment: seems to be =((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a [very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72518409/5021056) solved 7 months ago:

To fix this error for Jetpack Compose and Paging 3 you only need to use only this libraries

```
//ROOM
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.4.2"

// Paging 3.0
implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha15'
```

Hope this helps or try following some of the other suggestions from the source! Note I see this answer is about **2.4.3** specifically so check out an answer from the related question that came in December 2022 for that specifically.